# EF4 / SQL Generating Group / Grouping entries

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working with MVC3 and EF4. I would like to create a multilingual FAQ functionality. I need to be able to somehow group these entries via groupId (So that I know that this question is the same question -just in different language). So for example I may have the same FAQ question and answer in different languages.

so having this table I would add a GroupId field, but how I make it so that I know that "this" entry belongs to this GroupId.

[image]

What's the best way to achieve this?? What's the best approach, most efficient.
thanks

Comment: I suspect you'd want a Group table and a foreign key to that so that you get a Group property, but I'm not quite sure I'm understanding the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you already have this feature in your current table. Use `FaqId` as your `GroupId`. Don't make the `FaqId` autogenerated and make `FaqId` + `LanguageId` your composite primary key. In such case your `FaqId` will point to all language mutations of a single question.

You can also do some normalization of your table. You can divide it into `Faq` (`FaqId` (PK), `LoginId`, `IsActive`, `CreateDate`) and `FaqLocalization` (`FaqId` (FK,PK), `LanguageId` (PK), `Question`, `Answer`). Selection of columns for these normalized tables depends on your further requirements. Once you have this normalization you can also modify `FaqLocalization` table and remove composite PK and add new `LocalizationId`(PK). `FaqId` (FK) will be your `GroupId`.

Comment: good solutions. I ended up doing the second approach, that is dividing it into two tables. thanks